# Make requests download a video file faster

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code to download .mp4 file, however it's taking too long per video. This doesn't have anything to do with my internet as wget is ramming through it like a sharp knife, while the following code is chugging along like an old cow.

I think the code is viewing the video in real-time and writing it to the computer, is that correct? Is there any other way to download the video as a whole instead, or a means to speed this download up via any other module?

```
def download_file(link,temp):
    r = requests.get(link,stream=True)
    folder_name = r"K:\Archive\Videos"
    existing_files = [file.replace(".mp4","") for file in os.listdir(folder_name)]
    if temp not in existing_files:
        with open(f"{folder_name}/{temp}.mp4","wb") as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
```

Going through the code, I'm starting to think that perhaps it's the part that's checking if the file exists that's taking up the time. I have 400,000 files in the folder, so perhaps this checking mechanism isn't efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I think your assessment is right.  Enumerating 400,000 files takes a lot of time.  So, you should cache it in a global.

```
existing_files = None

def download_files(link,temp):
    global existing_files
    if not existing_files:
        existing_files = [file.replace(... etc
```